# Creating Dialog issue in private Chat with Quickblox

Tags: swift, chat, quickblox, ios9.3

I am trying to implement private 1 to 1 chat with QuickBlox but following the Quickblox docs only shows for group chat in http://quickblox.com/developers/Chat#Create_dialog . When I try sending just single occupants_ids, it gives following error :

```
{
"errors": [
"Occupants_ids cannot be less than one."
]
}
```

I am hitting create Dialog API with following body :

```
{
"type": 3,
"name": "",
"occupant_id": "13822296"
}
```

Do I need to update some keys in my request body?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check: [Create new 1-1(private) chat dialog](https://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-chat_users-ios#Create_new_1-1.28private.29_chat_dialog)

Code from [documentaton](https://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-chat_users-ios#Create_new_1-1.28private.29_chat_dialog) work for me:

```
let chatDialog: QBChatDialog = QBChatDialog(dialogID: nil, type: QBChatDialogType.Private)
chatDialog.occupantIDs = [user.ID]

QBRequest.createDialog(chatDialog, successBlock: {(response: QBResponse?, createdDialog: QBChatDialog?) in completion?(response: response, createdDialog: chatDialog)

    print("sucess + \(response)")

}, errorBlock: {(response: QBResponse!) in

    print("response + \(response)")
})
```

Comment: Thats correct but its not in swift. Also, Is creating new dialog for 1-1 private chat NOT possible through "Create Dialog API Request" in https://quickblox.com/developers/Chat#Create_dialog?

Answer (score 0):

```
QBChatDialog *chatDialog = [[QBChatDialog alloc] initWithDialogID:null type:QBChatDialogTypePrivate];
chatDialog.occupantIDs = @[@(1530190)];

[QBRequest createDialog:chatDialog successBlock:^(QBResponse *response, QBChatDialog *createdDialog) {

} errorBlock:^(QBResponse *response) {

}];
```

you can use this and you should provide one occupantIds. If it works please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

```
 let user = QBUUser()
        user.id = UInt(arrDoctors[sender.tag].QuickBloxId)!
        user.fullName = arrDoctors[sender.tag].title.capitalizeFirst
        ServicesManager.instance().chatService.createPrivateChatDialog(withOpponent: user) { (response, dialog) in
            let chatvc = CHAT_STORYBOARD.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ChatViewController") as! ChatViewController
            chatvc.dialog = dialog
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(chatvc, animated: true)
        }
```